# Python: How can you iterate over a list that is nested inside a while-loop?

Tags: python, while-loop

I have the following code:

```
shape = input("Please enter your choice of shape? ")    

nthTime = ["second","third","fourth","fifth","sixth"]

while shape.lower() not in ["octagon","heptagon","hexagon"] :
    print("Please select a shape from the list!")
    shape = input("Pick a shape, for the " + nthTime + " time! ")
```

How can I achieve the outcome, that Python will iterate over the list 'nthTime', each time it passes through the `while-loop?

I could use a nested for-loop but of course this would run the whole list, which is not my aim.

Therefore, I conclude that I would need to use a nested while-loop; however I cannot figure out the exact syntax.

I'm hoping this will be a useful question for others also in the future.

Comment: A nested for loop under the while over `nthTime` **will** *iterate over the list each time it passes through the while-loop*. What is your problem?

Comment: may i guess you want something like `shape = input("Pick a shape, for the " + nthTime[iteration_index] + " time! ")`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this:

```
shape = input("Please enter your choice of shape? ")    

nthTime = ["second","third","fourth","fifth","sixth"]
undesired_shapes = ["octagon","heptagon","hexagon"]

indx = 0

while shape.lower() not in undesired_shapes:
    print("Please select a shape from the list!")
    shape = input("Pick a shape, for the " + nthTime[indx] + " time! ")
    indx += 1
    if indx >= len(nthTime):
        print 'Giving up !!'
        break
```

Answer (score 2):

Use a for-loop and break out of the loop only if the user enters the correct value

```
for iteration in nthTime:
    if shape.lower() not in ["octagon","heptagon","hexagon"]:
        print("Please select a shape from the list!")
        shape = input("Pick a shape, for the " + iteration + " time! ")
    else: break
else: print "You have wasted all your chances, try again later"
```

Comment: Thank you. Is it at all possible to iterate over a list using a while-loop?

Answer (score 0):

```
nthTime.reverse()

while shape.lower() not in ["octagon","heptagon","hexagon"] and nthTime:
    print("Please select a shape from the list!")
    shape = input("Pick a shape, for the " + nthTime.pop() + " time! ")
```

Comment: You don't need to reverse the list and essentially make it a stack...

Comment: No need to reverse. You can simply do `nthTime.pop(0)`

Comment: Or he could just define the string literals in the right order. It's a trivial question, I reversed to minimize the changes to the code.  I was showing him how to use a stack to exhaust the attempts.